# How to find the general term formula of this sequence?

Tags: difference-equations

Note that S [n] is the sum of the first n terms of the sequence a [n]. It is known that a [1]==1, and the sequence {S [n]/a [n]} is an equal difference sequence with a tolerance of 1/3. Find the general term formula of sequence a [n]

Let b [n]==S [n]/a [n], first work out the general term formula of b [n], and then operate the "?

```
RSolve[{b[n + 1] == b[n] + 1/3, b[1] == 1}, b[n], n]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear[a, b, m, S];

b[n_] = RSolveValue[
  {b[n + 1] == b[n] + 1/3, b[1] == 1}, b[n], n]

(* (2 + n)/3 *)

a[1] = 1;

S[n_] = Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}];

m = 5;
sol = Solve[Table[b[n] == S[n]/a[n], {n, 2, m}], 
 Array[a, m - 1, 2]][[1]]

(* {a[2] -> 3, a[3] -> 6, a[4] -> 10, a[5] -> 15} *)

seq = Array[a, m] /. sol

(* {1, 3, 6, 10, 15} *)

a[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]

(* 1/2 n (1 + n) *)
```

Verifying,

```
b[n] == S[n]/a[n]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

A friend provided me with the answer:

```
ClearAll["`*"]
sol = First@RSolve[{b[n + 1] == b[n] + 1/3, b[1] == 1}, b[n], n]
s[n_] = b[n] a[n] /. sol
sola = First@
  RSolve[{a[n + 1] == s[n + 1] - s[n], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]
Sum[1/a[n] /. sola, {n, 1, n0}]
```